# Probability of Winning in 30 turns?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

GAME: There's a spinner with four sections: Red, Green, Blue, and Bonus. In this scenario if someone lands on Bonus they lose their turn. If they land on either Red, Green or Blue they get a card from the respective colored deck. Each deck has 10 cards. All the 10 cards of a deck are unique and all three decks have the same set of 10 cards. So there are 3 cards in the game of the same rank but each has the color of its deck.

You are playing this game with 2 other people.

In order to win this game you need three cards each of the same rank but of different colors.

What's the probability of anyone winning within 30 turns?
Assuming no player lands on Bonus.

Here's how I went about it:
After 30 turns each person has 10 cards.
Probability= (3C3)(27C7)/(30C10)

But I don't think this is correct.

Comment: It should be immediately clear that after 30 turns they need not all have 10 cards, because of the Bonus.

Comment: That's true. I edited the question.

Comment: Is the question for *you* to win or for *anyone* to win?  Does the win have to take place right at turn 30, or can it be at some turn before turn 30 as well?

Comment: Anyone can win. The win just has to take place at or before 30 turns.

Comment: OK, thanks ... and fortunately that makes it a litttle easier ... but it's still quite nasty.  I would definitely compute the probability that there is *no* winning combination in anyone's hands and subtract that from 1... but that's still one hell of a calculation ...  if you're ok with an estimate, I would just run a computer simulation several thousand times ...

Comment: I would love to program a simulation but I'm expected to do it by calculation. This is for a report I'm working on.

Comment: Yikes!!  Sorry, just getting ready to sign off.  But here's what I would do: I would do the exact calculation for a much smaller number, say, 3 cards for each color, rather than 10. That one might just be feasible to actually do. But, it'll be clear from that that there is no nice formula for this, so then you use that as an argument for doing the computer simulation instead.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!!